# "too much recursion" error in JQUERY UI using accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to programatically handel the toggeling of Jquery UI accordion i want that if someone click to next button then it goes to next step after a hidden field is added here is what i wrote in the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Pro Plan Store</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#changeStep").on("click",function(){
        $("#step1content").append("<input type='hidden' name='step1done' id='step1done' value=''>");

    $('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active', 1);
  });

    var accordian = $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        active: false,
        beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
            var newIndex = $(ui.newHeader).index('h3');
            console.log(newIndex);        
            switch(newIndex){
                case 0:
                 //   $(this).accordion( "option", "active", 0 ); //Main page just set it to homepage again
                break
                case 1:
                    if($("#step1done").length > 0){
                        $(this).accordion( "option", "active", 1 ); //Main page just set it to homepage again
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("Please login first to choose plan"); 
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                break
                case 2:
                break                
            }

    }
    });



});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 id="logmein">Welcome Pro Plan Store</h3>
        <div id="step1content">
            <p>
            Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
            ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
            amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
            odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
            </p>

          <input type="button" value="Next" id="changeStep" />




        </div>
    <h3 id="chooseplan">Choose Plan</h3>
    <div id="step2content">
        <p>
            Choose Plan Here
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3 id="zoura">Checkout</h3>
    <div id="step3content">
        <p>
            Zoura Iframe
        </p>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i run it and see it in console it give me too much recursion error. as shown in the following error:

[image]

am i doing something wrong?? i am using all the stable versions of libraries. I also tried it by emulating the click on the head element of accordion but same error i am getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to do with your code that's been written:
you are trying to make "Choose Panel" active by doing $('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active', 1) on click of next button in first panel.

Before getting activated, the control goes to beforeActivate method. But in beforeActivate method, you are trying to activate the same panel. Now the control comes to beforeActivate method again before getting activated and hence in deadlock.

Why would you want to activate same accordion in beforeActivate method? This will never work.

Comment: Thanks mate for giving the idea :) yea i just need to prevent the default behavior if my logic is not done in the`beforeActivate` part else let the accordion do the default job

Answer (score 1):

Ok Thanks to Rag Answer i was able to find my problem i just need to preventDafult behavior as per my logic required so my code will become something like this:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Pro Plan Store</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#changeStep").on("click",function(){
            $("#step1content").append("<input type='hidden' name='step1done' id='step1done' value=''>");

        $('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active', 1);
      });

        var accordian = $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            active: false,
            beforeActivate: function(event, ui) {
                var newIndex = $(ui.newHeader).index('h3');
                console.log(newIndex);        
                switch(newIndex){
                    case 0:
                     //   $(this).accordion( "option", "active", 0 ); //Main page just set it to homepage again
                    break
                    case 1:
                        if($("#step1done").length < 0){
                            alert("Please login first to choose plan"); 
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    break
                    case 2:
                    break                
                }

        }
        });



    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3 id="logmein">Welcome Pro Plan Store</h3>
            <div id="step1content">
                <p>
                Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
                ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
                amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
                odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
                </p>

              <input type="button" value="Next" id="changeStep" />




            </div>
        <h3 id="chooseplan">Choose Plan</h3>
        <div id="step2content">
            <p>
                Choose Plan Here
            </p>
        </div>

        <h3 id="zoura">Checkout</h3>
        <div id="step3content">
            <p>
                Zoura Iframe
            </p>

        </div>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```